# ZL30251 phase aligned

Tags: voltage, clock, phase, oscillation, mems

I just want to confirm whether the part [zl30251](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.microchip.com/en-us/product/ZL30251&ved=2ahUKEwjft-2lo9P7AhX0IbcAHbBfBT4QFnoECA0QAQ&usg=AOvVaw0mwF8LT8pg3JHPay5bT4cF) has phase aligned outputs? If not, can it be aligned?

Also, I can confirm that both the outputs are LVCMOS.

Can you please help me with this?

Also, i searched that the other part [dsc2311](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.microchip.com/en-us/product/DSC2311&ved=2ahUKEwiRwv_Wo9P7AhV0UHwKHWnpAc4QFnoECBIQAQ&usg=AOvVaw2cm6ud9sPvefvu84eX1rKo) also has similar features.
But I cannot confirm from the datasheet that the clock outputs are LVCMOS. But I can see the outputs are phase aligned.

Can you help me?

Comment: Each output can be a different frequency to the other outputs hence they cannot be phase aligned when set up like this. Try reading the data sheet and press CTRL-F and type in "align" to get all hits. It's quite feasible that they will be aligned if the frequencies are the same and you do the adjustments specified.

Comment: One output is 12.8MHz and I want the other output to be twice the first one. In that case, can the starting edges be phase aligned?

Comment: Also, @Andyaka, could you also help on the LVCMOS outputs?

Comment: In your question you say that you have confirmed both outputs are LVCMOS @newbie

Comment: Yes is it correct

Comment: Also, can the outputs be phase aligned as the frequency i mentioned

Comment: Then you say: *could you also help on the LVCMOS outputs* and that confuses me; if you know they are LVCMOS, what help do you need in confirming that?

Comment: yeah, just required some confirmation. Sorry. What do you think about the frequency of the output clocks that I mentioned? If one frequency is twice the other frequency, can they be phase aligned?

Comment: The data sheet seems to indicate that @newbie but I've never used the device so I can only read what you can read!